# Change background image with remember feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, background-image

im currently creating a site where i want people to be able to change the background image. i have the script to change working just fine, but i'd like to include a "remember" feature.

here's my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var body = $(document.body);
    $('#backgrounds').bind('change', function(event){
        var bg = $(this).val();
        if(bg == null || typeof bg === 'undefined' || $.trim(bg) === '')
            body.css('background-image', '');
        else
            body.css('background-image', "url('" + bg + "')");
    });
});
```

how would i add a "remember" feature to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the background URL in the local storage if you're only targeting modern browsers.

Where you've declared `var bg = $(this).val()`, add a newline beneath it that should be like `localStorage.setItem('bg', bg);`.

Then underneath `var body = $(document.body);`, write: `if( localStorage.getItem('bg') ) { body.css('background-image', "url('" + localStorage.getItem('bg') + "');"); }`.

Comment: okay, added them lines but now the changer doesn't change at all. here's my code: 
`$(document).ready(function(){

    var body = $(document.body);

  if( localStorage.getItem('bg') ) { body.css('background-image', "url('" + localStorage.getItem('bg') + "');");

    $('#backgrounds').bind('change', function(event){
        var bg = $(this).val();

   localStorage.setItem('bg', bg);
        if(bg == null || typeof bg === 'undefined' || $.trim(bg) === '')

            body.css('background-image', '');

        else

            body.css('background-image', "url('" + bg + "')");

    });

});`

Comment: Sorry, remove the semicolon in `if( localStorage.getItem('bg') ) { body.css('background-image', "url('" + localStorage.getItem('bg') + "')[;]");`. I tested your code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MAbvu/2/) and found that the semicolon was the issue. Additionally, you haven't closed the local storage block, with a closing bracket, so the localstorage block should now look like `if( localStorage.getItem('bg') ) { body.css('background-image', "url('" + localStorage.getItem('bg') + "')"); }`. **Sorry, I just realised that I hadn't included that in the example.**